# Observable forkjoin subscribe types

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm making 2 API requests calls with typed responses, combining them into a single `Observable.forkJoin`. I want to get both results in different typed variables.

```
var observableOrganization: Observable<Organization> = this.getOrganizationDetails();
var observablePromotion: Observable<Promotion[]> = this.getPromotions();

Observable.forkJoin([ observableOrganization, observablePromotion])
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            organization: Organization = response[0];
            promotions: Promotion[] = response[1];
        },
        error => {
            // ...
        }
    );
```

How can I reach typed results in single subscribe response?

Comment: By "typed" you mean eg. this `Observable<Promotion[] | Organization >`? Or you want to merge the results?

Comment: I don't want the merged results, I prefer separated types.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve or what doesn't work to be honest...

Comment: in the .subscribe((response)) , the response type is  Organization[] by default. This is wrong, I made 2 api calls which gives me 2 different types(Organization and Promotion[]), not Organization[]

Comment: This is what you're doing https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts#L23, it returns `Observable<[Organization, Promotion[]]>`

Answer (score 34):

Use es6 destructuring also you can add types if they dont automatically assigned

```
 Observable.forkJoin([ observableOrganization, observablePromotion])
        .subscribe(([org, prom]: [Organization, Promotion[]]) => {
            organization:Organization = org;
            promotions: Promotions[] = prom
        },
        error => {
            //error here
        });
```

Comment: thanks for help, but I cant make this compile:  .subscribe([response1, prom]: [Organization, Promotion[]]) => {
            
        });

Comment: In the  .subscribe([org, prom]: gets this error: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Organization[]) => void'.

Comment: The problem probably in this lines of code var observableOrganization: Observable<Organization> = this.getOrganizationDetails();
var observablePromotion: Observable<Promotion[]> = this.getPromotions();

Comment: check the types of this functions

Comment: or update the question with full code will be easier.

Answer (score 8):

[`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) will only return "nice" types, when the requests are explicitly declared as [`ObservalbleInput`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/type-alias/ObservableInput).

I personally prefer this syntax, using the [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) language feature:

```
const requests: [ObservableInput<Organization>, ObservableInput<Promotion[]>] = [observableOrganization, observablePromotion];
Observable.forkJoin(requests)
    .subscribe(
        ([organization, promotions]: [Organization, Promotion[]]) => {
            // use organization and promotions here
        },
        error => {
            // ...
        }
    );
```

Comment: Isn't this rather due to the fact that you're explicitly typing your subscribe value here by doing : [Organization, Promotion[]. I didn't get this working in any case.

Comment: @rumblefx0 Are you sure, you used `ObservableInput` for *all* requests? It worked for me quite well.

Comment: Hmm, can you show how you instantiate observableOrganization & observablePromotion please?